# UWP/C# Date Storage in a Variable

Tags: c#, uwp

Now, ive bumped into so many different responses to the usage of Date in C#
Ranging from using:

```
DateTime.Parse
Date.Now
```

etc. There seems to me a huge amount of ways to use the time date funtion. What i need to do is Read the Day, Month and Year from say today (assuming Date.Now?) and store these values individually so that they can be referenced throughout the entire budget.

The way i was looking at doing this was by having the DateTimeStorage Class in its own Classes Folder. That way, i can reference it at any point throughout the entire project right?

The issue i have bumped into is that i get an error immediately with the following two lines within the class:

```
class DateTimeStorage
{
    String stringDate;
    DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(stringDate);       
}
```

According to this, stringDate has an error

> a field initialiser cannot reference the non-static field

Now, i was going to close the Class by storing the string values like below:

```
class DateTimeStorage
{
    String stringDate;
    DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(stringDate); 

     String day = datevalue.Day.ToString();
//etc
}
```

This doesnt work either, "dateValue does not exist in the current context"

Now, im completely stumped and not sure how best to approach this. There are so many different ways ive seen to do dates. Its hard to know if any of them work the way i need them to.

Would anyone have any suggestions? I need to store the variables as strings as they are going to be used through the entire project to populate fields etc.

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: What is that you're trying to achieve? The field initializer issue comes down to what's written in the error code - you can not initialize fields with non-static properties, but you can run the appropriate initialization code inside the class constructor.

Comment: Why do you need a "storage" for DateTime? It can simply store itself. Persistemce is an other stuff, but you havent mentioned that...

Comment: What im trying to do is store each part of the date in its own variable i.e Day, Month, Year as Strings. These variables will then need to be accessed throughout the whole solution/project so for an example, I would like to populate a TextBox with the current Month. Due to this being used multiple times across different XAML pages, i would like to use the variables to avoid having to copy paste code per page? Im really new to this so please excuse if im not makin sense. I dont even know if im making sense but it makes sense in my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a static class to store the current date. You could modify this such that the date is able to be updated from elsewhere in the code but this is the simplest approach that initializes the date to `Now` on program start up.

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary3
{
    public static class StaticDate
    {
        static StaticDate()
        {
            //Initialize Date
            var date = DateTime.Now;
            Year = date.Year;
            Month = date.Month;
            Day = date.Day;
        }

        public static readonly int Year;
        public static readonly int Month;
        public static readonly int Day;
    }

    public class SomeOtherClass
    {
        public void MethodThatNeedsDate()
        {
            var year = StaticDate.Year;
            var day = StaticDate.Day;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Out of interest, a ClassLibrary, is that used a lot? Im currently using the following: namespace "ProjectName".Classes I have not bumped into libraries as yet. Would it be best practive to use that? That is instead of what i was intending on doing, having a folder in the solution called "Classes" and having individual classes within that folder that i could reference?

Comment: You should really read up on the different types of projects. A class library is used to store and share code across other projects. The namespace in this sample is just the default when I created a new project but the code could be used in just about any project type.

Comment: I will have a read up now. Thank you. Im just picking this stuff up as i go so thank you for the heads up :) You guys are amazing. Ill try using this now and mark it if it works :)

Comment: Sorry JSteward, does your code store the date, year and month as numbers? Im assuming where you declare the readonly int that its the case? I just want to clarify so i can convert to a string if necessary?

Comment: Oh ok, yeah I was just using integers but you can use strings.

Comment: Added this in successfully to my code today and works perfectly. Marked as answer :)